# Where are sandbox e-mails to users sent?

Tags: email, sandbox

After creating a new sandbox I noticed that user e-mail addresses are changed to the following format `[nickname]=[company domain]@example.com`.

Is this a special redirect, or are these e-mails simply not being sent because they are pointing to the `@example.com` domain name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a change in the Spring 14 release. The emails are not sent.

> Starting in Spring ’14, whenever you refresh a sandbox all user email
>   addresses are modified to use an example domain. The Salesforce
>   message transfer agent ignores emails that end with @example.com, so
>   no emails are sent from a sandbox.

See page 258 of the [release notes](https://na8.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_spring14_release_notes.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this happening this week as well, and while I'm not sure, I suspect it's intentional so that people who aren't involved in the sandbox don't get emails that really aren't relevant.

IE: If Bob in development is working in the sandbox to write new accounting workflows, should Jill really be getting email alerts about sandbox orders ready for approval?